# ParametricPlot3D as a ContourPlot

Tags: complex, parametric-functions, plotting

I want to plot the amplitude of a complex-valued function of one complex variable. I want to do this in the plane defined by the real and imaginary parts of the complex variable as a `ContourPlot`.

For example, a simple function

$f(z)=\frac{z}{e^{g}-z\,e^{-i\,k}}$

where

$z=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2+y^4}}\,e^{i\,v}$ is the complex variable, with $1\geq y\geq 0$ and $2\,\pi>v\geq 0$. $g$ and $k$ are some positive constants. I want a plot of $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ as a function of $Re\,(z)$ and $Im\,(z)$ and not as a function of $y$ and $v$.

The only way I know how to do this is using `ParametricPlot3D` with a function where I explicitly put in the definition of `z` and figure out its real and imaginary parts to put in as the first two arguments of `ParametricPlot3D`, that is

```
fTest2[y_, v_] := (y/Sqrt[1 - y^2 + y^4] E^(I v))/(E^g - y/Sqrt[1 - y^2 + y^4] E^(I v) E^(-I k))

Block[{k = \[Pi]/3, g = 5/10}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{y/Sqrt[1 - y^2 + y^4] Cos[v],y/Sqrt[1 - y^2 + y^4] Sin[v], Abs[fTest2[y, v]]}, 
{y, 0, 1}, {v, 0,2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: ParametricPlot3DTest]

It should be possible to present this as a contour plot, where the height (amplitude of the fucntion) is encoded in the colour of the contour plot. However, I do not know how to do this and would like to learn. The naive exercise of just plugging in the function into `ContourPlot` leads to

```
Block[{k = \[Pi]/3, g = 5/10}, 
 ContourPlot[Abs[fTest2[y, v]], {y, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi] }, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
```

[image: ContourPlotTest]

which as expected is a plot in terms of `y` and `v` and not the real and imaginary parts of `z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[z_] := z/(Exp[g] - z Exp[-I k])

ComplexContourPlot[
 Abs[Evaluate[f[z] /. {k -> \[Pi]/3, g -> 1/2}]], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 8]
```

[image: Complex contour plot of modulus of a function]

The restriction that `z = (y/Sqrt[1 - y^2 + y^4])Exp[I v]` for `0 <= y <=1` and `0 <= v <= 2 Pi` is equivalent to `Abs[z] <= 1`, so we include the latter `RegionFunction` restriction in the plot:

```
 ComplexContourPlot[
    Abs[Evaluate[f[z] /. {k -> \[Pi]/3, g -> 1/2}]], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, 
    PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 12, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{z}, Abs[z] <= 1]]
```

[image: Complex contour plot with restricted domain]

Comment: You haven't added the `RegionFunction -> Function[{z}, Abs[z] <= 1]` part to the arguments of `ComplexContourPlot` which we reached the conclusion is needed.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: your original question didn't ask for such a restriction on `z`, so far as I can see.

Comment: If you look at the form of `z` in terms of `y` and `v` and the coordinate ranges for `y` and `v` you will realise that there is a restriction on `z`. Do you understand what is shown with the ParametricPlot3D?

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: There is a bit of work to be done to show that the restrictions `0 <= y <= 1` and `0 <= v <= 2 \[Pi]` on `z = v + I y` in fact is equivalent to `Abs[z]<=1`.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: The issue with the range of `z = y + I v` (I had them reversed in previous comment) is that `y/Sqrt[1 - y^2 - y^4]` becomes nonreal at `Sqrt[(Sqrt[5]-1)/2]`.

Comment: To first comment: There is some work indeed. `ParametricPlot3D` does it for you, hence why I was asking for an equvailent `CountourPlot`.
To second comment: What I have given has a plus before `y^4`

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: Oops - missed that sign on `y^4`. In that case, it's now trivial to verify that the restrictions `0 <= y <= 1` and `0 <= v <= 2 \[Pi]` on` z = v + I y` in fact are equivalent to `Abs[z]<=1`: `y/Sqrt[1 - y^2 + y^4]` is a continuous function of `y` with values lying between 0 and 1, inclusive, and taking values 0 and 1 at 0 and 1, respectively, hence has range the closed interval from 0 to 1. And or course `Exp[I v]` has range the unit circle. So I'll modify my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your function correctly, in terms of strictly complex variables, your function is the composite `f@z` where:

```
f[z_] := z/(Exp[g] - z Exp[-I k])
z[w_] := Re[w]/Sqrt[1 - Re[w]^2 + Re[w]^4] Exp[I Im[w]]
```

For the 3D plot we may use the newish `ComplexPlot3D` function:

```
ComplexPlot3D[
 Evaluate[f@z[w] /. {k -> \[Pi], g -> 1/2}], {w, 0, 1 + 2 \[Pi] I}]
```

[image: 3D plot of amplitude colored by phase]

Then for the desired contour plot of the amplitude use `ComplexContourPlot`(new in Mathematica 12.1):

```
Block[{k = \[Pi], g = 1/2},
 ComplexContourPlot[Evaluate[Abs[f@z[w]]], {w, 0, 1 + 2 \[Pi] I}]
 ]
```

[image: Contour plot of amplitude]

Comment: Maybe I have not expressed myself clearly. I want a contour plot of $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ as a function of $Re\,(z)$ and $Im\,(z)$. The above produce plots of $f(z)$ as a function of $y$ and $v$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ThunderBigg: no, that does *not* make sense to me, as ostensibly `z` is a function of `y` and `v`Otherwise, what's the point of having your expression for `z` in terms of `y` and `v`? Of course you could just use `ComplexContourPlot[Abs[f[z]],...]` but then the expression for `z` in terms of `y` and `v` is irrelevant, as are the parameters `g` and `k` which enter into the definition of `z` in terms of `y` and `v`!

Comment: Do you see what is the difference between the result of `ParametricPlot3D` and the `ContourPlot`? They both show the amplitude of the function (one through height in 3D the other through changing colours in 2D), but the x- and y-axes represent different things. For `ParametricPlot3D` you need to have the form of `z` in order to figure out its real and imaginary parts which are what the x- and y-axes show. On the `ContourPlot` the x- and y-axes have different ranges since they show `y` and `v`. Do you see that difference between the x- and y-axes on the 2 plots in my post?

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: What function of what complex variable are you really trying to plot. I plotted what your post gave: `f[z[v + I y]]`.

Comment: Ok, forget about the definition of `z` in terms `y` and `v`. We just have $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^{g}-z\,e^{-i\,k}}$. Now plot the amplitude of this ($\lvert f(z)\rvert $) as a function of $\mathrm{Re}\,(z)$ and $\mathrm{Im}\,(z)$.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: Then just `ComplexPlot3D[
 Evaluate[f[z] /. {k -> \[Pi], g -> 1/2}], {z, 0, 1 + 2 \[Pi] I}]` for 3D and `ComplexContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs@f[z] /. {k -> \[Pi], g -> 1/2}], {z, 0, 1 + 2 \[Pi] I}]` for 2D (or set the values of `g` and `k` in a `Block` or similar construct).

Comment: Oh, I didn't find `ComplexContourPlot` on the website, it didn't get recommended when looking at `ContourPlot`. When taking into account the form of `z` in terms of `y` and `v` we see that `Abs[z]<=1`, which can be implemented as `Block[{k = \[Pi]/3, g = 5/10}, 
 ComplexContourPlot[Abs[fTest[z]], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{z}, Abs[z] <= 1], PlotRange -> All]]` . I guess, more complicated functions `z` can be implemented by playing around with the `RegionFunction`. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: I still don't understand what function of what complex variable you're trying to plot! If your `fTest` is the same as your original `fTest2`, then *it is not a function of `z`, but rather of a new complex variable `y + I v`*.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add, `fTest[z_] := z/(E^g - z E^(-I k))` is just $f(z)$ from the question

Comment: @ThunderBiggi: You suggest "more complicated function `z` can be implemented....". But `z` is the independent variable of the function `fTest` and *not* a function of some other variable according to your definition of `fTest` and your use of both `z` and `fTest`. `fTest happens to depend on parameters `g` and `k`, but `z` does *not* so depend.

Comment: the only reason we know `z` belongs to the unit disc is because of its form in terms of `y` and `v` and the ranges of `y` and `v`. This is why the `ParametricPlot3D` result looks they way it does. Is that clear?